# How to web scrape from two websites in one script?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a model and need to gather information not just regarding game results 
(this link https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/4991/fnatic?startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-12-31) 
but I would also like the script to open another link within the HTML source.. the link is available in the source and it'll take me to a page that explains each matches detailed result, 
(as in who want what round, https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/89458/cr4zy-vs-fnatic?startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-12-31&contextIds=4991&contextTypes=team), the main objective is I want to know who won the match (from first link) and who won the first round of each individual match (in the second link). Is this possible? This is my current script;

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/maps/6665/Astralis')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('tr')
AstralisResults = []

for result in results[1:]:
    date = result.contents[1].text
    event = result.contents[3].text
    opponent = result.contents[7].text
    Map = result.contents[9].text
    Score = "'" + result.contents[11].text
    WinorLoss = result.contents[13].text
    AstralisResults.append((date,event,opponent,Map,Score,WinorLoss))

import pandas as pd
df5 = pd.DataFrame(AstralisResults,columns=['date','event','opponent','Map','Score','WinorLoss'])
df5.to_csv('AstralisResults.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

So I would be looking for the following information:

```
Date | Opponent | Map | Score | Result | Round1Result |
```

Comment: what is score and how is it different from result? Perhaps show an example output row with actual figures from given links.

Comment: I also don't see the second link contained within the first. Are you actually getting any info at present as appears to be cloudflare protected?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site blocks if you scrape too fast, so had to put in a time delay. There's ways to make this code more efficient, but overall, I think it gets what you asked for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time


headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/4991/fnatic?startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-12-31' , headers=headers)
print (r)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('tr')
df5 = pd.DataFrame()

cnt=1
for result in results[1:]:
    print ('%s of %s' %(cnt, len(results)-1))
    date = result.contents[1].text
    event = result.contents[3].text
    opponent = result.contents[7].text
    Map = result.contents[9].text
    Score = "'" + result.contents[11].text
    WinorLoss = result.contents[13].text

    round_results = result.find('td', {'class':'time'})
    link = round_results.find('a')['href']


    r2 = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org' + link ,headers=headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
    round_history = soup2.find('div', {'class':'standard-box round-history-con'})

    teams = round_history.find_all('img', {'class':'round-history-team'})
    teams_list = [ x['title'] for x in teams ]



    rounds_winners = {}
    n = 1
    row = round_history.find('div',{'class':'round-history-team-row'})
    for each in row.find_all('img',{'class':'round-history-outcome'}):
        if 'emptyHistory' in each['src']:
            winner = teams_list[1]
            loser = teams_list[0]
        else:
            winner = teams_list[0]
            loser = teams_list[1]

        rounds_winners['Round%02dResult' %n] = winner
        n+=1


    round_row_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rounds_winners,orient='index').T

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[date,event,opponent,Map,Score,WinorLoss]],columns=['date','event','opponent','Map','Score','WinorLoss'])
    temp_df = temp_df.merge(round_row_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    df5 = df5.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    time.sleep(.5)
    cnt+=1

df5 = df5[['date','event','opponent','Map','Score','WinorLoss', 'Round01Result']]
df5 = df5.rename(columns={'date':'Date',
                          'event':'Event',
                          'WinorLoss':'Result',
                          'Round01Result':'Round1Result'})

df5.to_csv('AstralisResults.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
print (df5.head(10).to_string())
       Date                                 Event     opponent       Map     Score Result Round1Result
0  20/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019        CR4ZY     Dust2  '13 - 16      L       fnatic
1  20/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019        CR4ZY     Train  '13 - 16      L       fnatic
2  19/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019  mousesports   Inferno   '8 - 16      L  mousesports
3  19/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019  mousesports     Dust2  '13 - 16      L       fnatic
4  17/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019        North     Train   '16 - 9      W       fnatic
5  17/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019        North      Nuke   '16 - 2      W       fnatic
6  17/07/19  Europe Minor - StarLadder Major 2019      Ancient    Mirage   '16 - 7      W       fnatic
7  04/07/19                  ESL One Cologne 2019     Vitality  Overpass  '17 - 19      L     Vitality
8  04/07/19                  ESL One Cologne 2019     Vitality    Mirage  '16 - 19      L       fnatic
9  03/07/19                  ESL One Cologne 2019     Astralis      Nuke   '6 - 16      L       fnatic
```

Comment: This does not give back the above, instead it returns the Map and result of each individual round. Is there a way to get a csv file like the output you mentioned above? and can it be limited to just the first round?

Comment: @Kreeshee, have you not looked at the output?? It does give back this result. You need to check all the columns (I reordered them to show you this output, but it's all there). Secondly, yes, you can limit to just the first round. Have you not used Pandas before? I updated the solution.